# classifying reducible 2-dimensional mod-p Galois representations

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

I want to classify reducible $2$-dimensional mod-$p$ Galois representations of a field $E$ of characteristic $p > 0$ (i.e. representations $G_E = \mathrm{Gal}(E^{sep}/E) \to GL_n(\mathbf{F}_p)$)
$$
    0 \to \mathbf{F}_p \to V \to \mathbf{F}_p \to 0
$$
using étale $\phi$-modules.  Without loss of generality, one can (by twisting with a character) assume one of the $1$-dimensional representations trivial:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \chi & * \\
    0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
Since two $\phi$-modules given by matrices $X, Y$ are equivalent iff there is a matrix $A$ such that $X = AY\phi(A)^{-1}$, calculating with étale $\phi$-modules gives us
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & a \\
    0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x & y \\
    0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -a^p \\
    0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x & y - a^px + a \\
    0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
Note that if $\chi = \mathbf{1}$, i.e. $x = 1$, this gives us Artin-Schreier theory.

Can one do more explicitly?

Comment: Timo, you mean: the representations of the absolute Galois group of your field $E$ ? and $E$ is any field of characteristic $p$ ?

Comment: "Yes" to both questions.